# Resolve Cipher Suites from ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol in .NET 5

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, .net-5, tls1.3, tls1.1

.NET 5 has breaking changes with TLS. So when I'm connecting to a website (via `HttpClient`) and it does not support TLS 1.3 (which is the default for .NET5), I get the following error:   `Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:1414D172:SSL routines:tls12_check_peer_sigalg:wrong signature type.`

I wonder if I will BITOR the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol:   `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;`
will it resolve to giving the webserver the correct cipher suites?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a discussion on github: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22507

Based off from that, here's my solution. I had to read tons of github discussions as well as going through the runtime repo.

```
// Windows OS throws PlatformNotSupportedException for explicit list of TlsCipherSuite
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
{
    services.AddHttpClient("WebsiteCheck"), configureClient =>
    {
        configureClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    });
}
else
{
    services.AddHttpClient("WebsiteCheck"), configureClient =>
    {
        configureClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var allowedCipherSuites = Enum.GetValues<TlsCipherSuite>();

        return new SocketsHttpHandler()
        {
            SslOptions = new()
            {
                CipherSuitesPolicy = new CipherSuitesPolicy(allowedCipherSuites)
            }
        };
    });
}
```